# Implementing Image-Triggered Speech to Text Recognition in Website Slideshow using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on a website where I want to display multiple images, each staying on the screen for 6 seconds. Concurrently, I aim to allow users to comment on each image during its display time. Despite having code without errors, my speechResults array always remains empty. I specifically don't want continuous recording, but rather to capture comments made during each 6-second interval when an image is displayed. The recording should start with the image display, end after 6 seconds, and save the results. Upon a new image appearing, the process should repeat. Below is my HTML and JavaScript code. What might be the issue with the speech recognition not capturing any results?

```
<script defer src="/javascripts/list.js"></script>
<script defer src="/javascripts/slider.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <img id="imageDisplay" src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

this is my javascript code

```
let currentIndex = 0;
const imageDisplay = document.getElementById('imageDisplay');
const denominazione = [
    {
        "01": 'night'
    },
    {
        "02": 'see'
    },
    {
        "03": "dog"
    },

];

let recognition;  // Declare recognition as a global variable
let speechResults = [];  // List to store speech results

function showNextImage() {
    if (currentIndex < denominazione.length) {
        const currentEntry = denominazione[currentIndex];
        const imageNames = Object.values(currentEntry)[0];
        const imageName = Array.isArray(imageNames) ? imageNames[0] : imageNames;
        const imagePath = `/images/sand/${imageName}.png`;

        console.log(imagePath);
        imageDisplay.src = imagePath;

        // Start speech recognition during the image display
        startSpeechRecognition();

        // Wait for 6 seconds before stopping recognition
        setTimeout(() => {
            recognition.stop();

            currentIndex++;

            if (currentIndex === denominazione.length) {
                console.log('FINISH');
                console.log('Speech Results:', speechResults);
            } else {
                showNextImage();
            }
        }, 6000);
    }
}

// Function to start speech recognition
function startSpeechRecognition() {
    recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.lang = 'it-IT';

    recognition.continuous = false;
    recognition.interimResults = false;

    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        const userSpeech = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        console.log('User said:', userSpeech);
        speechResults.push(userSpeech);
    };

    recognition.start();
}

// Start the slideshow
showNextImage();
```

What am I doing wrong?